# Cutting a html source up

Tags: c#

```
Overall
</a></td>
<td align="right">14</td>
<td align="right">2,277</td>
<td align="right">2,619,106,616</td>
```

Let's say we have that and I want the 2,277 in a string how would I cut it?

Answer (score -1):

The simple approach which is not formally correct: Use a regular expression like `<td[^>]*>([^<]+)</td>` to extract the values. This should work well if you are reasonably sure that the regex you write will only match what you want.

If you need to be more exact or if regexes are to fragile (e.g. due to the website occasionally changing) you might want to use a proper HTML parser like [dcsoup](https://github.com/matarillo/dcsoup) and access the elements using CSS selectors or by manual traversal.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7897176

Comment: The question was not about parsing, but simply about getting values out of a (potentially very simple) HTML/XML snippet. Regexes are not formally correct, but do the job quick and pretty often very well.

Comment: My comment was a tad tongue-in-cheek.